# Comparing Cards Logic

Tags: java

I am trying to do a crazy 8 card game and I find it very difficult comparing the cards. Take for example, 3 of Diamond should match Jack of Diamond or a Queen of Diamond or a 4 of Diamond et cetera. Can you please help me with the logic in doing this. How do I compare these cards in my Main class? Also, How do I compare the card on the board to the cards in the player hand. For example, the card on the board is 3 of spades and the player has a 2 of spades which can be play on the board card. How do I compare these?
So far, this is what I have written.

```
public class Card {
protected int suit;
protected int rank;


         protected String[] suits = { "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds"};

         protected String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7", "8", "9","10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

public Card(int rank, int suit){
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;


}

public int getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public void setSuit(int suit) {
    this.suit = suit;
}

public int getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public void setRank(int rank) {
    this.rank = rank;
}
public String toString(){
    return this.ranks[rank] +" of "+ this.suits[suit];
}
```

}

```
  public class Deck {
  private ArrayList<Card> cards; //initialize cards arrayList using the card class

/*
 * Create a deck of cards
 */

public Deck() {
    cards = new ArrayList<>();

    /*
     * Fill the ArrayList with all of the cards to build a deck
     */

    for (int a = 0; a <= 3; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b <= 12; b++) {
            cards.add(new Card(a, b));
        }
    }
    Collections.shuffle(cards); // shuffle the deck of cards
}

/*
 * Draw card by "removing" it from the filled cards array
 */

public Card drawCard() {return cards.remove(0);}

public int getTotalCards() {return cards.size();}
```

}

```
 public class Hand{
ArrayList<Card>handOfPlayer;
String playerName;
public Hand(){

    handOfPlayer = new ArrayList<>();

  }





public ArrayList<Card> getHandOfPlayer() {
    return handOfPlayer;
}

public void setHandOfPlayer(ArrayList<Card> handOfPlayer) {
    this.handOfPlayer = handOfPlayer;
}


//print out he cards in player hand
    public ArrayList<Card>addCard(Card newCard){
    handOfPlayer.add(newCard);
    return handOfPlayer;

}

public void displayHand(){
    for(int i =1; i<handOfPlayer.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(i + ": "+ handOfPlayer.get(i));
    }
}
//Display number of cards in player hand
public void displaySize(){
    System.out.println(handOfPlayer.size());
}

public String getPlayerName() {
    return "Welcome! "+ this.playerName;
}

public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
    this.playerName = playerName;
}

public Card removeCard(int removeCard){
    Card cardOfCard = handOfPlayer.remove(removeCard);
    return cardOfCard;
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe I don't get exactly the question: just comparing ie card1.getSuit() == card2,getSuit() ?

Comment: The link below explain the rules of the game. Maybe when you read it, you can better understand what I am talking about.https://www.pagat.com/eights/crazy8s.html

Comment: @Intelligent thats a dead link for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your compare/equals method, but this would be the logic for card1.equals(card2):

```
if(card1.getSuit() == card2.getSuit())
    return true;
else
    return false
```

Comment: I thinki the OP want to just match two card based on suit.

Comment: I was fooled by the `String[] suits =`, my bad

Comment: @RC. no worries man, I originally wrote it with .equals but then realized it was int as well

Comment: Yes, I want to match cards base on suites. You are right Felice Pollano.

Comment: @Intelligent alright I edited out the extra stuff in my answer, should be very clear now